# Convert accented and encoded characters into their plain English ASCII equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, cyrillic

I have a problem where I need to perform the following kind of conversions:

```
éclair => eclair

bär => bar

привет => privet

こんにちは => konnichiva
```

As you can see the idea is that any language gets converted into the plain English ASCII equivalent. The áčçéñtèd letters are converted into their plain equivalents, letters in cyrillic or japanese encoding are converted into into their transliterated equivalent.

Anyone knows of a good way or - better - a Node.Js library to do that?

Comment: This is not a duplicate – I asked for a Node.Js module that can do that.